# Behavior of 'grep -w -f" when there are multiple/incomplete matches

Tags: regex, macos, bash, grep

I am using `grep -w -f` to extract lines from a file that match a pattern. However, if there is an incomplete match with a pattern in the input pattern file, it appears to be masking the complete match that appears later in the input pattern file. Is there another `grep` option that I am missing? For example:

```
$ head list
tt140
tt1351
tt1354
tt998
tt1122

$ head match1
tt135
tt1122
tt1351

$ grep -w -f match1 list
tt1122
```

It appears that the first pattern `tt135` in `match1` interferes with the later `tt1351`. If the first line is removed, the `tt1351` match is reported.

```
$ head match2
tt1122
tt1351

$ grep -w -f match2 list
tt1351
tt1122
```

Is this the expected behavior? Is there another option to pass to `grep` to avoid this?

Comment: Works for me. What version of `grep` do you have? What OS? Are you sure there are no hidden characters in either file?

Comment: I think he is using Mac. I can replicate the issue with BSD `grep`.

Comment: Repro'd, also mac/BSD grep. Does appear to be a bug. If you put tt135 after tt1351 it works too.

Comment: @MarcusRickert Yes, order matters, if 1351 comes first, it matches.

Comment: You can sort match1 by length, then: `perl -e 'print for sort { length $b <=> length $a } <>' match1`

Comment: This happens on Mac 10.8.5 and there are no hidden characters in the files. I'll try one of the suggested workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, as @japyal states, there appears to be **bug in the *BSD* version of `grep`** (which also affects OSX).

**Workaround**:

```
 grep -f <(sed 's/.*/\\<&\\>/' match1) list
```

This dynamically encloses the strings in `match1` in *explicit word-boundary regex assertions*, as if `match1` had been defined as:

```
\<tt135\>
\<tt1122\>
\<tt1351\>
```

The net effect is the same as if `-w` had been specified.

Comment: or use `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$0 in a' match list`. `;)`

Comment: @jaypal: That works well with the specific input, but doesn't generalize well. If you wanted generic word-boundary matching with `awk`, you'd have to use regexes with word-boundary matching _in `awk`_ - sadly, FreeBSD `awk` doesn't support word-boundary assertions, and rolling your own would be nontrivial.

Comment: I tested this answer with larger lists and matches in some scripts and it solves the problem. Thanks for the help -- I was completely baffled by this behavior and happy to hear it was a bug!

Comment: @xtrio You're welcome; glad to hear it. I encourage you to also file a bug with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com (which, I hope, will be paid attention to, even though it's a BSD utility).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify match1 as suggested by mklement0 , you could create the -w -f functionality using shell cmds to construct an equivalent grep cmd :

```
> egrep `cat match1 | xargs -d '\n' | sed 's/^/(\\</; s/$/\\>)/; s/ /\\>|\\</g;'` list
tt1351
tt1122
```

I don't have Mac or BSD to verify, but this works on linux for me.

Explanation : The part in backticks is constructing the desired regexp, which is then used in a vanilla egrep cmd.

```
> cat match1 | xargs -d '\n' | sed 's/^/(\\</; s/$/\\>)/; s/ /\\>|\\</g;'
(\<tt135\>|\<tt1122\>|\<tt1351\>)
```